# Why does PHP 7 add an array to stdClass, if the name come from an array?

Tags: php

I have a code snippet (not mine), that is acting different in PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.

Code:

```
$obj->order = new stdClass;
$obj->address = new stdClass;
foreach($item as $key=>$value){
        $k = explode(".", $key);
        if(...) {
            if($k[0] == 'order') $obj->order->$k[1] = $value;
            elseif ($k[0] == 'address') $obj->address->$k[1] = $value;
        }
}
```

There are a few values for $key:

- order.week
- order.weekfrom
- ...
- order.params

(PHP 7) print_r prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [order] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Array] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => json
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

(PHP 5.6) print_r prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [order] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [week] => ...
                    [weekfrom] => ...
                    ...
                    [params] => json
                )
        )
)
```

I have to change the Code to get the same results:

```
$obj->order = new stdClass;
$obj->address = new stdClass;
foreach($item as $key=>$value){
        $k = explode(".", $key);
        $foo = $k[1]; // insert var and add k[1] to it
        if(...) {
            if($k[0] == 'order') $obj->order->$foo = $value;
            elseif ($k[0] == 'address') $obj->address->$foo = $value;
        }
}
```

What happens imo is, that PHP 7 always overides the value added to the stdclass with

> $obj->order->$k[1]

If I use

> $obj->order->$foo

the values are appended.

Could somebody explain what happens here? I will gladly provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a documented change in the way PHP handles [indirect variables, properties and methods](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect):

In PHP 5, the expression:

```
$obj->order->$k[1]
```

is interpreted as `$obj->order->{$k[1]}`.

In PHP 7 it is interpreted as `($obj->order->$k)[1]`

You can use curly braces inside the expression to tell PHP how you want to interpret the [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php#language.variables.variable):

```
$obj->order->{$k[1]} = $value
```

(and it works as well in PHP 5.)

Comment: thank you for the doc. I was searching for something like this but didn't know what I am looking for.